# Adding second conf folder to JBoss 5.1.0

Tags: classloader, jboss5.x

We have a slightly modified JBoss 5.1.0 configuration, where we have added a new folder called `<JBOSS_HOME>/myconf` to the classpath. Here is the pertinent bit of `conf/jboss-service.xml`:

```
<server>
    <classpath codebase="${jboss.server.lib.url}" archives="*"/>
    <classpath codebase="${jboss.common.lib.url}" archives="*"/>
    <classpath codebase="myconf" archives="*"/>
    ...
</server>
```

The idea being that application-specific configuration files can go into `<JBOSS_HOME>/myconf` while JBoss-specific configuration files can remain in `<JBOSS_HOME>/conf`.

In `myconf` I have a file called `myapp_log4j.xml` which is a standard Log4J configuration file. This file is loaded by an AOP interceptor using `getResourceAsStream("/myapp_log4j.xml")`.

If the .xml file is in the following location it works:

```
<JBOSS_HOME>/myconf/conf/myapp_log4j.xml
```

though if it is in this location, it doesn't:

```
<JBOSS_HOME>/myconf/myapp_log4j.xml
```

Why does the .xml file need to be inside a conf subfolder, and is there any way we can change/fix this?

Comment: The single `conf` folder is core to how JBoss works. Why isn't your application-specific config inside the application itself?

Comment: Stick with it, it's the right thing to do. Messaging with the internals of JBoss, on the other hand, ain't.

Comment: @skaffman: Thanks, if you want to add that as a proper answer then I can accept it :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To summarise the comments, trying to put application-specific config into a separate `conf`-style JBoss directory is doomed to failure. JBoss isn't meant to bend that way.

App-specic config should go either (a) inside the application (i.e. inside the EAR/WAR), or (b) somewhere outside of JBoss entirely.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree.  We've been using custom classpath entries for years with no issues.  We find it to be a very efficient way to swap out classpath configurations.  I think your issue is that JBoss is expecting a URL.  E.g.,

```
<classpath codebase="file:/home/me/myProject/myBranch/patches" archives="*"/>
<classpath codebase="file:/home/me/myProject/myBranch/lib" archives="*"/>
<classpath codebase="file:/home/me/myProject/myBranch/ext/" archives="*"/>
<classpath codebase="file:/home/me/myProject/myBranch/"/>
```