# How to add external properties file to classpath in jboss 4.2

Tags: java, jboss

I want to read an external properties file when launching Jboss 4.2 . I want to add it to the classpath to read it from a WAR file . I have seen different solutions with Jboss 6 using modules, but I haven't seen anything related to JBoss 4.2.

I have included inside 'jboss-service.xml' the following code :

```
    <!-- Bean for reading properties -->
    <mbean code="org.jboss.varia.property.SystemPropertiesService"      
     name="jboss.util:type=Service,name=SystemProperties">
     <!-- Load properties from each of the given comma separated URLs -->
     <attribute name="URLList">
            ./conf/path.tmview.properties
     </attribute>
    </mbean>
```

In this file I have defined the property :

```
    property-placeholder filepath=/var/tmview_props/tmview/tmview.properties
```

This property is used in the following bean definition

```
   <bean id="tmviewConfigurerLocation"   class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
      <constructor-arg value="${property-placeholder-filepath}" />
   </bean>
```

inside an applicationContext.xml . When I launch jboss, the file of properties is read

```
    15:45:29,939 INFO  [SystemPropertiesService] Loaded system properties   
    from: file:/D:/devel/projects/tmview/deployment/jboss-
    ...ver/tmview/conf/path.tmview.properties
```

So, the property is read, but I kept obtaining the following exception

```
    2015-03-24 15:45:39,219 ERROR    
    [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context 
    initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could   
    not load properties; nested exception is 
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${property-placeholder-filepath} (The 
    system cannot find the file specified)
    at   
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.
    postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:78)
```

Is there any special way to read the property inside the spring bean ?

Answer (score 0):

In jboss 4 you was able to drop property files in the `<jboss_home>/server/<instance>/conf` directory and they would be available from the classpath.

Another possibility is add your custom directory to the classpath, to do this see [Adding second conf folder to JBoss 5.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669190/adding-second-conf-folder-to-jboss-5-1-0)

Comment: I have tried to put the file in conf with no results . The same adding a second conf folder .

Answer (score 0):

Ok . At the end , I solved the problem . It seems the problem was located in reading from application-context.xml .

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"   
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
            <value>file:${tmview.conf.variables}</value>    
    </property>
</bean>
```

I had to add a property placeholder reader . Regarding to jboss, you can read the parameter file either from conf/jboss-service.xml or deploy/properties-receive.xml, but it seems more appropiate to do the reading from the second one .